# Minimal configuration for jboss with dotcms

Tags: java, jboss, dotcms

I am currently developing a portal for a client, and as a part of the delivery, i have to give them minimal configuration of jboss 4.2.3GA
I want to ask You, if dotcms has any minimum system requirements specification.
If not, can you recommend me the best way to get that minimal configuration? 
I am using dotcms 1.7a with deploy on a cluster.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I know the best solution will be to start with `all` configuration and remove unnecessery services. I don't know dotCMS and cannot tell what services should be removed.

Here you can find more information about removing services from JBoss:

- [Tuning and Slimming JBossAS](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossASTuningSlimming)
- [JBoss 5.x Tuning/Slimming](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss5xTuningSlimming)